# Efficient method for convolution like sum evaluation

Tags: algorithm, fft, computational-geometry, convolution, mathematical-expressions

**Problem** Given N 3-dimensional points which are {$p_1,p_2,..,p_n$} where $p_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i) $ . I have to find the value of the formula

[image]

for some given constant integers P, Q, R, S.
all numbers are between 1 and M ( = 100).

I need an efficient method for the calculation for this formula

Please give any idea about how to reduce complexity better than $O(n^2)$

Comment: What are `P, Q, R, S` and their expressions like `Q(Yi - Yj)` supposed to be?

Comment: Alos, what does this have to do with FFT and Convolution?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Q(Yi-Yj) is the product of Q and (Yi-Yj) and  now corrected.

Comment: It appears that that expression can be evaluated fastly using convolution or fft etc . There is no specific reason

Comment: A) I see no reason to assume that FFT/convolution would be effective here , but B) I could be wrong because this is really a site for practical programming question rather than theoretical ones.  Yes, this question is a bit of both, but you might get a better esponse at one of CompSci sites: such as http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1425772/formula-reduction-to-some-physical-interpretation

Comment: Duplicate: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/217692/reduction-to-some-physical-interpretation-of-this-formula

Comment: Duplicate: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57322/reduction-to-some-physical-interpretation-of-this-formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all coordinates are between 1 and 100, then you could do this via:

1. Compute 3d histogram of all points O(100*100*100) operations.
2. Use FFT to compute convolution of histograms along each of the 3 axes

This will result in a 3d histogram of 3d vectors. You can then iterate over this histogram to compute your desired value.

The main point is that computing a convolution of histogram of values computes the histogram of pairwise differences of those values.  This can also be used to compute a histogram of sums of values in a similar way.

Comment: Can you explain it a little more please. i.e. how to compute 3D histogram and then convolutions. Maybe give some links for that

Comment: Some example tutorial and code for performing convolutions with the fft is available on [codechef](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/18331/farasa-editorial)

Comment: Can you please tell me more about 3D histogram .

Comment: That is nothing more than hist[xi][yi][zi] += 1 for each point

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like a particle potential problem (the kind you have in electrodynamics for instance), where you have to find some "potential" at the location `(x_j, y_j)` by summing all elementary contributions from the `i-th` particles.

The fast algorithm specific for this class of problems is the Fast Multipole method. Look up this keyword, but I must warn you it is by no means simple to understand or implement. Strong math background needed.